# Lombok doesn't work with spring-boot-maven

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, lombok

I have i project with spring-boot i used spring 2.0.5.RELEASE version. And i want to use the Lombok when i simplify my work for the getter and setter and the controctor with and without fields this is the file of my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>hr.access</groupId>
<artifactId>ms-EtudiantS-Formation</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>ms-EtudiantS-Formation</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF- 
     8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

And in the view of Outline I don't see the getters and setters when I select the window of my class This is the sourcecode of my Etudiant class:

```
package hr.access.entities;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Etudiant {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@Column(length = 80)
private String nom;
@Column(length = 80)
private String prenom;
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date dateNaissance;
```

}

What is my mistake in this code what do you write and add to my code because my class is correctly?

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is.

Comment: What do you mean with "**when I select the window of my class**". Also, be aware that Lombok does not generate code for you, it provides getters, setters, constructors, ... at compile time. Depending on which IDE you're using, you may also have to install a plugin so that the IDE is aware of the getters/setters/... .

Comment: @g00glen00b it provides it in compile time not run time

Comment: @SamirKamalGhoneim I noticed it already, should be fixed now. No worries though, as I was planning to delete my comment anyways as soon as the OP clarified his/her question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LomBok has a jar inside m2 folder (mvn cache folder)
eg: C:\Users\Mypc \ .m2 \repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.12 based on the mvn package  that has to be executed it will search for ide

[image]

and then you need to restart your ide then if you search within the class you can see getter and setters

Answer (score 7):

This should work, try it;

1. The project has `lombok` dependency. First look into your `.m2`
   repository and if not ,find the lombok jar!
2. **Double click** on jar, specify the path for IDE like `C:\Users\ide\install\package\yourIDE.exe`
3. Restart the `IDE` and update the maven project.

Comment: Here is the key, the problem is when you have several IDES in your sistem, in my case, I had Eclipse and Spring tool suite and Lombok dependency had installed in Eclipse therefoe in Spring tool suite doesn't works.

Comment: @LuisManrique  That is solved by Lombok plugins in various IDEs, isn't it ?  e.g. [Intellij Lombok plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok)

Comment: @GreenMarty That's right!

Answer (score 6):

if your problem is that you don't see the getters and setters that's not a problem as lombok provide it in compile time in `Etudiant.class` file
but you must use lombok plugin in your IDE

setup guide https://projectlombok.org/setup/overview

Comment: Indeed related to plugin. Confirmed for Visual Studio Code.

Comment: @adrianfilipescu yes you're right it support VScode 
https://projectlombok.org/setup/vscode